# Fixing while loop that contains a counter

Tags: java, while-loop

I have tried to add a counter to my program using a while loop but have not been able to get it working yet. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong, i got it to work a little bit but if i enter a correct value the "wrong" text will still come up, it wont break out of the loop.

```
public class Username {
    public static void main (String[]args) {    
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"};
        int j = 0;

        while (j < 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter your name");
            String name1 = kb.nextLine();
            boolean b = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
                if (name[i].equals(name1)) {
                    System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
                    break; // To stop loop checking names
                }
            }
            System.out.println("wrong");
            j++;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but doesn't that break just breaks you out of the for loop and not the while loop?

Comment: By the way if any of the answers below helped you, you need to click on the check mark below the votes to accept the answer. You haven't accepted any answers to any of your previous questions either. If you're being lazy about it, just know that every time you accept an answer, you get 2 reputation points.

Comment: Also note that some people who might ordinarily help you will decide not to if you have a history of failing to give proper credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal change to your code would be to use label and `break <label>;` - that'll break the loop marked with label, rather than the current loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


 public class Username
{


public static void main (String[]args)


{   
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    // array containing usernames 
    String [] name = {"barry", "matty", "olly","joey"}; // elements in array

    int j = 0;
outerloop:  while (j < 3)
            {

                System.out.println("Enter your name");
                String name1 = kb.nextLine();
                boolean b = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

                    if (name[i].equals(name1))
                    {

                        System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
                        break outerloop;// to stop loop checking names

                    }



                }
                System.out.println("wrong");
                ;j++;

            }

}}
```

For more details on labeled break see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: While this accomplishes the goal, the intentions would be much clearer by simply using a proper flag in the while loop. At minimum, a more descriptive name than `outerloop` should be chosen.

Comment: this worked for me thanks but it is not printing the error message when the incorrect details are being entered, do you know why?

Comment: @user3151959 hmm... it does for me. Moreover there's no way this code can miss printing "you are verified you may use the lift" or "wrong" disregarding the input. Could you please specify the exact input you've used?

Comment: when i enter any value that isnt in the array, i entered "j" it then just asks to enter your name again and when i enter j 3 times it terminates, it works its just not outputing the "wrong" message. the message for when i enter correctly works

Comment: Code specified in the answer does print "wrong" on unexpected input... Are you sure you are using _exactly_ the same code as specified in the answer?

Answer (score 5):

The outer loop, the `while`, is used for the allowed attempts. You need an additional way to signal it to break, since the `break` statement you have only breaks from the `for` loop. One such way is to use a `boolean` idicator:

```
boolean found = false;
int attempts = 0;
while (!found && attempts < 3) {
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name1 = kb.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        if (name[i].equals(name1)) {
            System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
            found = true;
            break;// to stop loop checking names
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }
    ++attempts;
}
```

Comment: @JasonC indeed, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Like Mr. Carlo said in his comment, the way you have your loop built makes the fastest fix one of inserting `j = 3` into your if statement.
What's happening, though, is that once it hits the break statement, it only exits the for loop, and because j is still 0 on the first run, it prints out the text, and keeps going. You just need to make the program recognize that the for loop has found a valid name, and tell the while loop that it can exit because of that.

**EDIT:** what I might do, in this case, might look like this:

```
while(j<3)//and all outside code being the same
{
    System.out.println("Enter your name");
    String name1 = kb.nextLine();
    boolean found = false;//renamed other-wise useless boolean
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    {
        if(name[i].equals(name1))
        {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("you are verified you may use the lift");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found)
        break;
    System.out.println("wrong");
    j++;
 }
```

Comment: This is a good quick fix, but it's worth noting that the OP should be careful to not fall into a general pattern here. It is often beneficial for code to echo intent, and in this case, the true intent is to "exit the loop when valid input is received", rather than "skip to the 3rd retry when valid input is received".

Comment: Yeah I like this better too. Sorry about my `j=3` suggestion in the comment above. I was being lazy and like I said it was `quick and dirty`. After thinking about it a little though I deleted the comment...

Answer (score 1):

You are using `j` as a "retry" counter to retry failed inputs. The problem is, you are not breaking out of your retry loop on *good* inputs.

`break` only breaks out of the inner most loop. I suggest also having a flag of some sort that the outer loop can check. For example:

```
int retries = 0;
boolean success = false;

do {
    ... get input;
    if (input is valid)
       success = true;
    else
       retries ++;
} while (retries < 3 && !success); 

if (success)
    all good;
else
    gave up after retries.
```

Logically, this echoes your intentions: Keep retrying until either the maximum retry limit is hit, or we've received valid input.